# How do I Delete geometry? Separate objects are one piece?

Tags: modeling, objects

I'm new to Blender but versed in Rhino, Sketchup and AutoCAD. That of course means my approach to creation has been influenced by those programs.

I read that to delete in Blender I must be in Object mode. I'm trying to delete the tapering tube. However, the two objects are one and "delete" removes everything. Shouldn't they be separate objects? I didn't combine or join. Can someone layout the method to delete a single object? 
Win 10, Blender 2.80

[image]

Comment: You must have joined in some way or your 2 objects are both selected. Try to reselect only one of the 2, if that's impossible, switch to edit mode, select the mesh you want to delete with L and delete

Comment: The shortcut P opens up the separate menu, if you want to split the geometry into two objects.

Comment: If you are an absolute beginner in Blender, go to page 4 in this scrapbook link. Therein, click on the playlists, all the best choices for novices. They will pull you up fast on Blender. https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/13UpIjJEE7Oa7x5BiMsjXGW5CGOTDF03-SocRYi4Babs/mobilepresent?slide=id.g646f12fe70d42be6_0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have the objects separated go to edit mode instead of object mode, then select one mesh pressing "L" while your mouse is over the mesh you want to select, then press "P" to separate the selected mesh into a new object.

When you're in edit mode it doesn´t matter if you add a new cube or cilinder it will be part of the same object you were editing on first place.

Answer (score 2):

If you add a new object while in edit mode, the new generated object will be added as part of the active object, but it will still be a separate mesh, means it's vertices, edges and faces are not fused with the object you add it to.

Thus it's possible to select a vertex, edge or face of the newly added object-mesh.
If you press "l", for *select linked* (it works as well as long as your cursor is close enough to the mesh), to select all connected vertices, edges or faces depending on which edit mode you are in.
After you selected the mesh you want to delete, press "x" and select *Vertices*, as that will delete all basis for the mesh, deleting edges or faces would still leave the vertices behind and would eventually need another clean up.

Should you decide not to delete the mesh/geometry you selected, press "p" for the *separate function* and go with "Selection", that will generate another object with the selected and now split of geometry.